# In Hindu mythology, is there any reference to a special, elite squad of soldiers?

Tags: reference-request, kings, soldiers

Like a special squad of soldiers (not an army) that a king or queen maintains for either special missions or special purpose (think Kingsguard from Game of Thrones).